# Was the design of the Ferengi marauder based on the Enterprise D's bridge?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, ferengi

Below you can see a couple of images of certain angles of the Enterprise D's bridge, compared with the Ferengi Marauder.  There is a striking similarity between them and I was wondering if the former was the basis of the design for the latter?

[image: Notice the circular section]

[image: Ferengi ship from front]

[image: And from the back]

[image: Ferengi ship from back]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Startrek.com, the Marauder ship (better known as a D'Kora Class) was designed by Andrew Probert and [inspired](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Official_Fan_Club_Magazine_issue_60) by the shape of a Horseshoe crab on the desk of Herbert J. Wright, Senior producer of Star Trek TNG.

*"The Ferengi ship I wanted to have, not only an obvious shape difference, but a textural difference as well. The original description of the Ferengi ship ship was a horseshoe crab design with a neck that would extend. The front of the ship I wanted to look fairly dangerous. Something that seems real dangerous-looking to me are the pincers on an earwig insect. I designed the front of the ship to basically have that shape. On the underside of the vessel is a boarding ramp which can be seen when the ship turns around. The back of the ship is basically used for cargo storage seeing how the Ferengi are traders."*

In the [script](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Last_Outpost_%28episode%29) of TNG : 'The Last Outpost' it's described as "*a strange horseshoe crab-like design*"

There is a very extensive description of the genesis of the design as well as a host of concept art [here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/D%27Kora_class_model)

[image]

Comment: That's interesting.  I just thought that there was quite a similarity.